# How do I write from a toString() into a txt.file

Tags: java, tostring, filewriter

I want to write from my toString () that are in a different class to a new text document by using FileWriter. toString () is in a class that implements an interface and I try to get it to another class where I have my FileWriter.
Anyone know if I can store it in an array, or how I interconnects toString () with my FileWriter located in another class?

```
        String myArray = toString();
        String writableString = "";

        for (String item : myArray) {
            writableString += item + ",";
        }

        writableString = writableString.substring(0, writableString.length() - 1);

        bw.write(writableString);
        bw.close();
```

The toString() from a different class:

Comment: Hey! You need an object/objects of the class with the toString-method.. then you can call object1.toString() and get the specific String of this concrete object.. This string you can write in your file.

Comment: `writableString += item + ",";` - Please use a StringBuilder ...

Answer (score 0):

The first problem here is that you don't have an instance of the class where you want to invoke your `toString()` method.
Make a variable which refers to your object first.

The second problem is that the `String` class is not `Iterable`, so you cannot have that `for` cycle on the `myArray` variable. The name of the variable (myArray) is quite deceptive.

You want to replace spaces with commas? Use `String.replace()`, like: `myArray.replace(' ', ',')`.